# Need to update parent object field based on multiple child records

Tags: apex, trigger, class

I'm trying to update parent object field based on all the records available in child object.

I have two objects A & B. A is parent and B is child, A is having a Pick list field 'Status', B is having check box field 'Completed'

Now 'Status'should be updated when its all the child records are checked 'completed'.

Here is the code i've written

```
 trigger updateParent on Project__c (after insert, after update) {
    boolean check = false; 
    Plan__c parentObj;
    List<Plan__c> somePlan; 

    List<Project__c> childsObj = new List<Project__c>([SELECT Id, Completed__c FROM Project__c WHERE PlanR__c = 'a0228000007O8Kr']);
    //childsObj = [SELECT Id, Completed__c FROM Project__c WHERE PlanR__c = 'a0228000007O8Kr'] ;

        for(Project__c child : childsObj){
            if(child.Completed__c == false){
                check = true; 
            }
        }

        if(check == false){
            parentObj = new Plan__c();
            parentObj.id = 'a0228000007O8Kr';
            parentObj.Status__c = 'Completed'; 
            update parentObj;
        }
    }
```

Please suggest an idea or share if any trigger available.

thanks in advance.

Comment: what you have done so far for this? we are here to help you but It will be great if you can show some effort prior to ask a question on SE.

Comment: I have done hard coding for this, getting multiple errors while bulkifying it...

Comment: Please share your code, so people can suggest fixes. People won't likely write a trigger for you but will gladly offer suggestions on how to improve what you wrote.

Comment: I have added the code in the question, trying to bulkfy this..

Comment: how do you know when all the child records have been entered? what happens if all current children are completed, hence marking the parent as completed and then a new child is added that is not complete?

Comment: You can just do this with rollups and a formula if you are clever. If it's not M/D use [DLRS](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries/commits/master).

Comment: Initially we will be loading the parent records and child records..when the sales rep checks true the 'completed' check box of all records for parent then the 'status' in parent should be updated. @crop1645

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here is a trigger according to your requirement !

here `Object A = Parent__c & Object B = Child__c` in my case

Trigger :

```
 trigger childTrigger on Child__c (after insert,after update) {
    childTriggerHandler objChildTrigHand = new childTriggerHandler();
    if(Trigger.isAfter) {
        if(Trigger.isInsert ) {
            objChildTrigHand.UpdateFields(Trigger.new);
        }
        if(Trigger.isUpdate ) {
            objChildTrigHand.UpdateFields(Trigger.new);
        }
    } 
}
```

Trigger handler :

```
/*
* This class Update status Fields of parent object in salesforce.
*/

public with sharing class childTriggerHandler {
    public void UpdateFields(List<Child__c> newList) {
        List<Parent__c> updateList = new List<Parent__c>();
        Map<id,List<Child__c>> mapParentIDAndChild = new Map<id,List<Child__c>>();
        boolean flag;
        set<Id> parenetTrue = new set<Id>();
        for(Child__c objChild : newList) {
            parenetTrue.add(objChild.Parent__c);
        }
        for(Child__c objChild : [select id , Completed__c , Parent__c from Child__c where Parent__c IN: parenetTrue] ){
            system.debug('<<<<<<objChild '+objChild );
            if(mapParentIDAndChild.containsKey(objChild.Parent__c)) {
                system.debug('<<<<<<in if 1st ');
                mapParentIDAndChild.get(objChild.Parent__c).add(objChild);
                system.debug('<<<<<<in if 1st mapParentIDAndChild '+mapParentIDAndChild);
            } else {
                system.debug('<<<<<<in else 1st ');
                mapParentIDAndChild.put(objChild.Parent__c,new List<Child__c>{objChild});
                system.debug('<<<<<<in else 1st mapParentIDAndChild '+mapParentIDAndChild);
            }
        }
        for(Id objId : mapParentIDAndChild.keySet()) {
            flag = true;
            for(Child__c objChild : mapParentIDAndChild.get(objId)) {
                if(objChild.Completed__c == false){
                    flag = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(flag == true) {
                updateList.add(new Parent__c(Id = objId , Status__c = 'Updated'));
            } else {
                updateList.add(new Parent__c(Id = objId , Status__c = 'In-progress'));
            }
        }
        if(!updateList.isEmpty()) {
            update updateList;
        }

    }// end of UpdateFields
}// end of childTriggerHandler
```